# How to add Headers on RESTful call using Jersey Client API

Tags: rest, request, header, jersey

Here is the Format for RESTful call:

```
HEADERS:
    Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
    Authorization: Bearer Rc7JE8P7XUgSCPogjhdsVLMfITqQQrjg
    
REQUEST:
    GET https://api.example.com/1/realTime?json={"selection":{"includeAlerts":"true","selectionType":"registered","selectionMatch":"","isTheEvent":"true","includeRuntime":"true"}}
```

Here is my code:

```java
Client client = Client.create();
WebResource webResource = 
        client.resource("https://api.example.com/1/realTime?json=
        {"selection":{"includeAlerts":"true","selectionType":"registered","selectionMatch":"","isTheEvent":"true","includeRuntime":"true"}}");

//add header:Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
webResource.setProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");

//add header: Authorization Bearer Rc7JE8P7XUgSCPogsdfdLMfITqQQrjg
value = "Bearer " + value;
webResource.setProperty("Authorization", value);

MultivaluedMap<String, String> queryParams = new MultivaluedMapImpl();
queryParams.add("json", js);

//Get response from RESTful Server
jsonStr = webResource.get(String.class);
```

But it returns error

```
com.sun.jersey.api.client.UniformInterfaceException: GET https://api.example.com/1/realTime? returned a response status of 500
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:607)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.get(WebResource.java:187)
    at net.yorkland.restful.GetThermostatlist.GetThermostats(GetThermostatlist.java:60)
```

I think I didn't add headers correctly.

Can someone help me to fix it? Please give me advice how to add headers on request.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think you're looking for header(name,value) method. See [`WebResource.header(String, Object)`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/1.17/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/client/WebResource.html#header(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object))

Note it returns a Builder though, so you need to save the output in your webResource var.

Comment: Hi The Architect, Thank you for your solution. I did it, but the result is not my expected. Could I set parameters and headers at the same time. Please see my following post.

Answer (score 41):

I use the header(name, value) method and give the return to webResource var:

```
Client client = Client.create();
WebResource webResource = client.resource("uri");

MultivaluedMap<String, String> queryParams = new MultivaluedMapImpl();
queryParams.add("json", js); //set parametes for request

appKey = "Bearer " + appKey; // appKey is unique number

//Get response from RESTful Server get(ClientResponse.class);
ClientResponse response = webResource.queryParams(queryParams)
    .header("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
    .header("Authorization", appKey)
    .get(ClientResponse.class);

String jsonStr = response.getEntity(String.class);
```

Comment: I saw that on your question you were creating a String for your "appKey", that was correct? appKey = "Bearer " + something ??

Comment: Hi eLRuLL, if we give a name to "Bearer appKey", it should be better for using authorizationStr. However, in order to reduce the using memory for creating new variable. I use appKey="bearer" + appKey. Please let's me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 18):

Try this!

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();

String jsonStr = client
            .target("http:....")
            .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)

            .header("WM_SVC.NAME", "RegistryService")
            .header("WM_QOS.CORRELATION_ID", "d1f0c0d2-2cf4-497b-b630-06d609d987b0")

            .get(String.class);
```

P.S You can add any number of headers like this!

Comment: Is there a way to add a dynamic amount of headers?

Answer (score 6):

If you want to add a header to all Jersey responses, you could also use a `ContainerResponseFilter`, from [Jersey's filter documentation](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html#d0e9365) :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Provider
public class PoweredByResponseFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext)
        throws IOException {

            responseContext.getHeaders().add("X-Powered-By", "Jersey :-)");
    }
}
```

Make sure that you initialize it correctly in your project using the `@Provider` annotation or through traditional ways with `web.xml`.

Comment: worked for me! the provider annotation `@Provider` did the trick

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for.  We are creating proxies with WebResourceFactory.newResource(), and this looks like the way to do it.

Comment: While using the solution, it is important to use the same import statement, otherwise, you can make mistake in using the snippet. Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 3):

```
String sBodys="Body";
HashMap<String,String> headers= new HashMap<>();
Client c = Client.create();
WebResource resource = c.resource("http://consulta/rs");
WebResource.Builder builder = resource.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
builder.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
if(headers!=null){
      LOGGER.debug("se setean los headers");
      for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : headers.entrySet()) {
          String key = entry.getKey();
          String value = entry.getValue();
          LOGGER.debug("key: "+entry.getKey());
          LOGGER.debug("value: "+entry.getValue());
          builder.header(key, value);
      }
  }
ClientResponse response = builder.post(ClientResponse.class,sBodys);
```

Answer (score 1):

This snippet works fine, for sending the Bearer Token using Jersey Client.

```
    WebTarget webTarget = client.target("endpoint");

    Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder =  webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    invocationBuilder.header("Authorization", "Bearer "+"Api Key");

    Response response = invocationBuilder.get();

    String responseData = response.readEntity(String.class);

    System.out.println(response.getStatus());
    System.out.println("responseData "+responseData);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ClientResponse response = webResource
                               .queryParams(queryParams) //
                               .header("Content-Type", "application/json") //
                               .header("id", "123") //
                               .get(ClientResponse.class) //
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how I do it.

```
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Entity;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedHashMap;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

Gson gson = new Gson();
Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, String>>() {
}.getType();
MultivaluedMap<String, String> formData = new MultivaluedHashMap<String, String>();
formData.add("key1", "value1");
formData.add("key1", "value2");
WebTarget webTarget = ClientBuilder.newClient().target("https://some.server.url/");
String response = webTarget.path("subpath/subpath2").request().post(Entity.form(formData), String.class);
Map<String, String> gsonResponse = gson.fromJson(response, type);
```