# Jersey 2.x: How to add Headers on RESTful Client

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jersey-2.0

I've already looked at [How to add Headers on RESTful call using Jersey Client API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18342456/how-to-add-headers-on-restful-call-using-jersey-client-api), however this is for Jersey 1.x.

How do I set a header value (such as an authorization token) in Jersey 2.21?

Here is the code I'm using:

```
public static String POST(final String url, final HashMap<String, String> params)
{
    ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig();
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(config);

    WebTarget target = client.target(url);

    String data = new Gson().toJson(params);

    Entity json = Entity.entity(data, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);
    Invocation.Builder builder = target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);
    return builder.post(json, String.class);
}
```

Comment: It's pretty much the same thing in the Jersey 2. Hint, look a the javadoc for [`Invocation.Builder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/Invocation.Builder.html)

Comment: There's a pretty good answer by @rgettman - if it solves the question, you should accept it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Jersey 2.0+, you can register a custom implementation of [`ClientRequestFilter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/ClientRequestFilter.html) that can [manipulate the headers](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html#d0e9470) in the request that the Client API will send out.

You can manipulate the headers via the `ClientRequestContext` parameter that is passed into the `filter` method.  The [`getHeaders()` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/ClientRequestContext.html#getHeaders--) returns the `MultivaluedMap` on which you can `put` your header(s).

You can [register](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/client.html#d0e4388) your custom `ClientRequestFilter` with your `ClientConfig` before you call `newClient`.

```
config.register(MyAuthTokenClientRequestFilter.class);
```

Answer (score 13):

If you want to add only few headers in Jersey 2.x client, you can simply add it when request is sending as follows.

```
webTarget.request().header("authorization":"bearer jgdsady6323u326432").post(..)...
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to what Pradeep said, there's also headers(MultivaluedMap < String, Objects> under WebTarget.request() if you have a gaggle of headers:

```
MultivaluedMap head = new MultivaluedHashMap();

head.add("something-custom", new Integer(10));
head.add("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");

builder.headers ( head ); // builder from Joshua's original example
```