# Jersey 2 - Simple Client Get with Headers Example

Tags: java, rest, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

I'm trying to do a simple get with headers using `Jersey2`. I read through [Jersey 2.x: How to add Headers on RESTful Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32532959/jersey-2-x-how-to-add-headers-on-restful-client) to help create my code below, but I'm not having much luck. I created the `clientRequestFilter` as suggested, but don't know how to register it with the client properly, which I think may be my core issue.

I'm hoping to get a sanity check to see what I'm doing wrong need it be registering the `ClientRequestFilter` or if I'm missing more than that. Below is the documentation of the webservice I'm trying to consume and my jersey2 client code to try to consume it.

**Web Service Documentation:**

EXAMPLE GET (to “read” Customer with ID #1)

```
GET https://myportal.0.site.com/ApiService.svc/Customer/1 HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json 
Token: <enter your unique token here> 
Host: myportal.0.site.com 
Content-Length: 0
Connection: Keep-Alive 
ServerName: myportal
```

**My Logic:**

Below is the pom and code.

The pom dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

The code:

```
    final String portal = "myportal";
    final String host = portal + ".0.site.com";
    final String baseURL = "https://" + host + "/ApiService.svc";
    final String token = "00000-0000-0000-0000-0000-000000";
    final String getCustomer1URL = baseURL + "/Customer/1";
    final String contentType = "application/json";
    final String contentLength = "0";
    final String connection = "Keep-Alive";

    try {

        // Headers for client.
        ClientRequestFilter clientRequestFilter = new ClientRequestFilter() {
            public void filter(ClientRequestContext clientRequestContext) throws IOException {
                clientRequestContext.getHeaders().add("Token", token);
                clientRequestContext.getHeaders().add("ServerName", serverName);
                clientRequestContext.getHeaders().add("Content-Type", contentType);
                clientRequestContext.getHeaders().add("Content-Length", contentLength);
                clientRequestContext.getHeaders().add("Connection", connection);

            }
        };

        ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig();
        Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().newClient(config);

        //GET Request
        final Response response = client.target(getCustomer1URL).request().get();

        if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + response.getStatus());
        }
        String output = response.readEntity(String.class);
        System.out.println("Output from Server... \n");
        System.out.println(output);
        client.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**What I'm Getting:**

With the above, I'm getting a response of `<!DOCTYPE html>` with html as a webpage including javascript... Which makes me think that perhaps I didn't craft something properly or that I'm not setting the headers properly or something else. Hoping someone can give me a sanity check on what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't registered `clientRequestFilter` with your `ClientConfig`. Do something like below -

```
 ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig();
 config.register(clientRequestFilter);
 Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().newClient(config);
```

Although, I prefer to create a separate class for `clientRequestFilter` and register that class -

```
 config.register(HeadersClientRequestFilter.class);
```

By this, Jersey will automatically handle creation and destruction of the `ClientRequestFilter` objects.